# Nginx reverse proxy not keeping url when passing requests to AWS ac2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a nginx reverse proxy configured in a cloud service outside aws, and I'm trying to keep the original url when requesting a service deployed on ec2. My config below:

```
http {

  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name example.com;
    location /blog {
      proxy_pass http://ec2.instance.com;
    }
  }

}
```

But when I call example.com it redirects to ec2.instance.com/blog and not example.com/blog. I tried to include "proxy_set_header Host $http_host;" but didn't work as well.

```
http {

  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name example.com;
    location /blog {
      proxy_pass http://ec2.instance.com;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
  }

}
```

Doing that the page keeps loading forever and I receive a timeout.

Do you know what could be the problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: I am not able to understand this. As per the first example if your write http://example.com/blog then it will be redirected to http://ec2.instance.com. Now tell me what is your requirement here.

Comment: Hello @MayurJain, I want to preserve example.com/blog when I hit this url in the browser, but instead of keeping example.com/blog I see ec2.instance.com/blog and not example.com/blog.

Comment: As per my knowledge " proxy_pass http://ec2.instance.com;"  this entry is enough to achieve your requirement. There should be some issue.